# Is it possible to update pipeline parameter value from mapping data flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

**use-case :**

Trying to create a pipeline which receives bulk data from source SQL and to sink to different tables in destination SQL based on one column. The column dedicates the table name in the destination.

I have declared a parameter at data flow which needs to be updated based on the column value and use the same value as dynamic table name in the sink.

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware,it is impossible.

According to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-data-factory-mapping-data-flows-public-preview-adds-parameter-support/),you can get values and change them from pipeline in data flow,but you can't update them from data flow.

Hope this can help you.